# How to redirect in react if prop is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I'm passing props from another page into this page and it works fine. So I decided to copy the route of the receiving page into another tab, so it throws this error:

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'myData' of undefined
```

which is understandable because no props were passed. What I want to do is to route to another page since there's no prop defined with the below line of code:

```
   componentDidMount() {
        this.props.location.state.myData === undefined && this.props.history.push('/');

        this.fetchData(data);
   }
```

But it's not working, it's giving me the same error as above. What could I be doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using React Router? Can you apply this logic in the router rules rather than in a child component?

Comment: How do you mean, Ryan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, it isn't saying that `myData` is undefined, it's saying that it can't read the *property* `myData` of undefined. I.e the `state` property of `location` is undefined.

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.location.state === undefined) {
    this.props.history.push('/');
    return;
  }
  // else
}
```

Comment: if `location` isn't always guaranteed to be an object, you'll have to check for `this.props.location && this.props.location.state === undefined`